# how to make a command happen after a certain time discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I made a tictactoe command but i want the game to end if no one places anything after 30 seconds how would I do that i want it to reset tho if someone places an x or a o like if i do -place 4 then the other person takes 10 seconds then places then it resets to 30 seconds. if you need the code for the ttt command for some reason its below:

```py
player1 = ""
player2 = ""
turn = ""
gameOver = True

board = []

winningConditions = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
]

@client.command(aliases=["ttt"])
async def tictactoe(ctx, p1: discord.Member, p2: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send("To place do -place <1 - 9>")
    global count
    global player1
    global player2
    global turn
    global gameOver

    if gameOver:
        global board
        board = [":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:",
                 ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:",
                 ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:", ":white_large_square:"]
        turn = ""
        gameOver = False
        count = 0

        player1 = p1
        player2 = p2

        
        line = ""
        for x in range(len(board)):
            if x == 2 or x == 5 or x == 8:
                line += " " + board[x]
                await ctx.send(line, delete_after=300)
                line = ""
            else:
                line += " " + board[x]

        # determine who goes first
        num = random.randint(1, 2)
        if num == 1:
            turn = player1
            await ctx.send("It is <@" + str(player1.id) + ">'s turn.")
        elif num == 2:
            turn = player2
            await ctx.send("It is <@" + str(player2.id) + ">'s turn.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("A game is already in progress! Finish it before starting a new one.")

@client.command()
async def place(message, ctx, pos: int):
    global turn
    global player1
    global player2
    global board
    global count
    global gameOver



    if not gameOver:
        mark = ""
        if turn == ctx.author:
            if turn == player1:
                mark = ":regional_indicator_x:"
            elif turn == player2:
                mark = ":o2:"
            if 0 < pos < 10 and board[pos - 1] == ":white_large_square:" :
                board[pos - 1] = mark
                count += 1

                # print the board
                line = ""
                for x in range(len(board)):
                    if x == 2 or x == 5 or x == 8:
                        line += " " + board[x]
                        await ctx.send(line, delete_after=300)
                        line = ""
                    else:
                        line += " " + board[x]

                checkWinner(winningConditions, mark)
                print(count)
                if gameOver == True:
                    await ctx.send(mark + " wins!")
                elif count >= 9:
                    gameOver = True
                    await ctx.send("It's a tie!")

                # switch turns
                if turn == player1:
                    turn = player2
                elif turn == player2:
                    turn = player1
            else:
                await ctx.send("Be sure to choose an integer between 1 and 9 (inclusive) and an unmarked tile.")
        else:
            await ctx.send("It is not your turn.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Please start a new game using the -tictactoe command.")



def checkWinner(winningConditions, mark):
    global gameOver
    for condition in winningConditions:
        if board[condition[0]] == mark and board[condition[1]] == mark and board[condition[2]] == mark:
            gameOver = True
```

Answer (score 0):

i would use wait_for if it's only 30 seconds and only needs a response. Here is a link on how to use wait_for it is a very helpful link try to read a bit of it at least. Link: https://vcokltfre.dev/tutorial/15-waiting/